# Regular expression for comma-separation except if the comma is within parenthesis

Tags: c++, regex

I need to separate a string like this:

`cat, dog , ant( elephant, lion(tiger)), bird`

into this:

```
cat
dog
ant( elephant, lion(tiger))
bird
```

My current state is this: `(\w+)(,\s*)*`, but that also separates elephant, lion and tiger. Further, some commas and spaces are kept.

You might have guessed, that I will call the same expression again on the `ant(...)` string in a further iteration. If important, I'll use this in c++.

Comment: That doesn't look like a regular language. You'll need a stronger kind of parser.

Comment: Possibly equivalent to http://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348.

Comment: Don't know if regex is the way to go, but you can do this with a really simple c/c++ parsing function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This regex](https://regex101.com/r/K2T3xO/1):

```
(\w+\(.+\))|\w+
```

Will parse

```
cat, dog , ant( elephant, lion(tiger)), bird
```

Into:

```
cat
dog
ant( elephant, lion(tiger))
bird
```

Full program:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string str{R"(cat, dog , ant( elephant, lion(tiger)), bird)"};
    std::regex r{R"((\w+\(.+\))|\w+)"};

    std::vector<std::string> result{};
    auto it = std::sregex_iterator(str.begin(), str.end(), r);
    auto end = std::sregex_iterator();
    for(; it != end; ++it) {
        auto match = *it;
        result.push_back(match[0].str());
    }
    std::cout << "Input string: " << str << '\n';
    std::cout << "Result:\n";
    for(auto i : result)
        std::cout << i << '\n';
}
```

[live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aaf8ccb51fb8a31c)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, will test it tomorrow. What function does the `R` in front of the `string`/`regex` have?

Comment: @dani It is a [raw string literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) and it [makes it possible](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19075999/1460794) to write the regex string [without escaping](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape) all the slashes.